# How can I defer the $scope / $element $destroy event so I can animate the element inside a directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using Angular 1.0.8, I want to know if it's possible to defer the $destroy event of a DOM node (or the scope), and execute it (the $destroy event) only after the animation (through CSS3) of the element is done. Is it possible? I have a filter that change the listing of a couple of `inline-block`s and I want to animate them (scale in / out) as they are added / destroyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not easy to do in Angular 1.0.x; however, this is [a core feature in AngularJS 1.2](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) via [the `$animate` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24animate) (which has methods like `leave`, which removes the DOM element and calls a callback once animations are done) and [the `ngAnimate` module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate).